# AppScript - Custom function update on row value change

Tags: google-apps-script

Currently my custom AppScript function has an argument that is the row the function is being called. (Because [you can't find the location where a function is called apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29228697/google-apps-script-get-cell-where-the-function-is)).

To have the input be the row, I use a separate column that is used as an input (ranges `B2-B29` whom's values are 2-29). **Because** the auto complete sequence that one usually get's from dragging across cells doesn't work for custom functions (apparently). *I.e.* you can't have a cell `MYFUNC(1)` right below it have `MYFUNC(2)`, then select both and drag down to get `MYFUNC(3)` etc.

But because the input is static (reliant on the unchanging range `B2-B29`) when the row values change I have to set `B2-B29` to something else and then rewrite `B2-B29` to the values I want.

It works so I can live with it but I want to know if there's a better way to approach this problem. I would like a way to have my function recalculated on the values. Now since it's all numerical my current solution is to take the sum of the row and then pass that in but that's a hack.

Comment: You could always have a column of the numbers lets say A1:A29 then in B1 =MYFUNC(A1).  Now when you drag down it will replace A1 with A2 to A29 and the values in B2 to B29 will reflect the values in A2 to A29.

Comment: @TheWizEd that's what I did. I will rewrite my answer to make it more clear.

Comment: Your assumptions seem to be wrong  and your question is Unclear. Show your apps script and explain input and outputs and the problem clearly with a [mcve]